# how to make user defined routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have one doubt in ruby on rails...i have a problem in routes file.i am working for 1 week.but i am not getting a appropriate result.my problem is. i am working on a project called canvas which is a online tutorial.In that project in the course home page it have a side menu called pages.when clicking that it goes to the url. The canvas version is rails 2

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/1/wiki/front-page
```

and its routes file for the page is

```
 concern :wikis do
get 'pages' => 'wiki_pages#pages_index'
get 'pages/:wiki_page_id' => 'wiki_pages#show_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :named_page
get 'pages/:wiki_page_id/edit' => 'wiki_pages#edit_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :edit_named_page

resources :wiki_pages, :path => :wiki do
  match 'revisions/latest' => 'wiki_page_revisions#latest_version_number', :as => :latest_version_number
  resources :wiki_page_revisions, :path => :revisions
end
match 'wiki/:id' => 'wiki_pages#show', :as => :named_wiki_page, :id => /[^\/]+/
end
```

my task is to add two more links to side menu named as faq and career without controller and view. i have put the routes for faq and career routes as below:

```
 concern :faq do
get 'faq' => 'wiki_pages#pages_index'
get 'faq/:wiki_page_id' => 'wiki_pages#show_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :named_page
get 'faq/:wiki_page_id/edit' => 'wiki_pages#edit_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :edit_named_page

resources :wiki_pages, :path => :wiki do
  match 'revisions/latest' => 'wiki_page_revisions#latest_version_number', :as => :latest_version_number
  resources :wiki_page_revisions, :path => :revisions
end
match 'faq/:id' => 'wiki_pages#show', :as => :named_faq_page, :id => /[^\/]+/
end
```

the career routes is

```
 concern :career do
  get 'career' => 'wiki_pages#pages_index'
  get 'career/:wiki_page_id' => 'wiki_pages#show_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :named_page
  get 'career/:wiki_page_id/edit' => 'wiki_pages#edit_page', :wiki_page_id => /[^\/]+/, :as => :edit_named_page

  resources :wiki_pages, :path => :wiki do
    match 'revisions/latest' => 'wiki_page_revisions#latest_version_number', :as => :latest_version_number
    resources :wiki_page_revisions, :path => :revisions
  end

  match 'career/:id' => 'wiki_pages#show', :as => :named_wiki_page, :id => /[^\/]+/
```

end

using the above wiki_controller i want to change the url like below
when i clicking the faq the url must like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/1/faq/front-page
```

but the actions are wikipages_index and show.

when i clicked the career link it must be.

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/1/career/front-page
```

like this the url must come for all index and show,edit and update.plz apologize me that it is not an standard english.can  anybody help me.
                             thanks in advance
                                                                           with regards
                                                                            saran

Comment: question is not clear. I think your need to refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths